# Parsing Data for Label using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, labeling, python-parser

I have field called PIN in my parcels shapefile. Formatting looks like this: xx-yy-zzzzz, just much longer.  I want to split the first two sections on one line and the third (the z's) on the next.  I figured I could do this with an expression in 'Label Expression', but do not know how to parse every record in a field.

So basically I want this to do something like this:

```
PIN[:5] + "\n" + PIN[6:]
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're having trouble with varying length of strings between hyphens and that your record is in the format xx-yy-zzzz, i.e. always two hyphens.

You can use advanced labeling ticking the advanced checkbox and choosing parser: python. A simple method is to use `string.split` which returns a list of the substrings between the *split char*:

```
def FindLabel([PIN]):
    Values = [PIN].split('-')
    return('{}-{}\n{}'.format(Values[0],Values[1],Values[2]))
```

Where `\n` is the newline character for a label.

Comment: Thank you, this is not exactly what I was trying to do (I should have provided the actual PIN), but it was a enough to steer me in the right direction.  Here's what I came up with:                                                       `def FindLabel([PIN]):                                                                                                     
    values = [PIN][:15] + "\n" + [PIN][16:]                                                            
    return values`